# Difficulties when swapping 2 arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, swap, partial

I wrote a code that arrays different names and I want to order alphabetically, so far I managed to swap just the first name:

i.e: 1st name Nicu Bogdan
     2nd name Andrei Dan
     3rd name Martin Adrian

After running the code I get
Andrei Bogdan
Martin Dan
Nicu Adrian

Is it possible to use pointers to solve this issue?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Names {
    char nume[10];
    char prenume[10];
} Name[2];

 int main()
{
    struct Names Name[3]={{"Nicu","Bogdan"},
                          {"Andrei","Dan"}, 
                          {"Martin","Adrian"}};
    int i,j;
    char temp[20];
    int n=3;
    int cmp;
    char tmp[20];


    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n-1; j++)
        {
            cmp = strcmp(Name[j].nume, Name[j+1].nume);

            if (cmp > 0)
            {
                strcpy(tmp, Name[j+1].nume);
                strcpy(Name[j+1].nume, Name[j].nume);
                strcpy(Name[j].nume, tmp);
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s %s \n", Name[i].nume, Name[i].prenume);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You're already swpping `nume`, so swap `prenume` as well.

Comment: *Is it possible to use pointers to solve this issue?* Yes it is possible but in your case if you simply follow dbush's comment, your task would be done.

Comment: If you want to exchange the complete contents of `Name[j], Name[j+1]`, then `{ struct Names t; t = Name[j]; Name[j] = Name[j+1]; Name[j+1] = t; }`  Is this your goal?

Comment: Use structure assignment; it's simpler.  That's what @chux said, without using the words 'structure assignment'.  If you need to copy structures, copy them.  The only time you have to worry is if you have pointers etc inside the structure — then you need to be a bit more careful.  How careful depends on what those pointers mean (are used for), and how your copy is going to be used.  Although you can't do direct array assignment in C, you can do them indirectly via structure assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments are suggesting that if you use a struct array rather than string arrays, along with an extra temporary storage instance of the same struct, the sorting can be a little simpler.  The following is basically your code, with a few changes.

Look at the comments for suggestions and explanations.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct {
    char nume[80];   // names are often longer than 10 characters.
    char prenume[80];// for simplicity, pick 80
} NAMES;  // create a typedef NAMES

int main(void)
{
    // use NAMES typedef to create instances of struct
    NAMES Name[3] = {{"Nicu","Bogdan"},
                     {"Andrei","Dan"},
                     {"Martin","Adrian"}};
    NAMES t; /// used for temporary storage during a swap

    int i,j;
    char temp[20]; // not used
    int n=3;
    int cmp;
    char tmp[20]; // not used


    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n-1; j++)
        {
            cmp = strcmp(Name[j].nume, Name[j+1].nume);

            if (cmp > 0)
            {
//              strcpy(tmp, Name[j+1].nume);
//              strcpy(Name[j+1].nume, Name[j].nume);
//              strcpy(Name[j].nume, tmp);
                // This is what comments are suggesting
                // each NAMES array element contains both first
                // and last names, therefore allowing a single
                // swap operation rather than 2 copying
                // operations per person. 
                t = Name[j];           
                Name[j] = Name[j+1];
                Name[j+1] = t;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s %s \n", Name[i].nume, Name[i].prenume);

    return 0;
 }
```

---

Edit: `qsort` works as well. For example:

```
int compareNames(const void *s1, const void *s2);

int main(void)
{
    int n=3;
    int i;

    NAMES Name[]={{"Nicu","Bogdan"},
                  {"Andrei","Dan"}, 
                  {"Martin","Adrian"}};

    //replace for/if statements with following line.
    qsort(Name, n, sizeof(NAMES), compareNames);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s %s \n", Name[i].nume, Name[i].prenume);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}



int compareNames(const void *s1, const void *s2)
{
    NAMES *e1 = (NAMES *)s1;
    NAMES *e2 = (NAMES *)s2;

    return strcmp(e1->nume, e2->nume);
}
```

---

> Is it possible to use pointers to solve this issue?

Yes. In fact, you are already using pointers in your code, and it would be very impractical to *avoid* using pointers, as that'd mean you can't use *any* arrays or functions meaningfully. See the annotations of one of your lines of code below for further details.

```
      // v function identifier expressions get converted to function pointers
cmp = strcmp(Name[j].nume, Name[j+1].nume);
           /*  ^       ^     ^         ^
            * Array expressions typically get converted to pointers
            */
```

If you wanted to express these *implicit, subtle* conversions explicitly, this is possible, for example by declaration:

```
typedef int *compare_function(char const *, char const *);
compare_function *compare = strcmp;
```

This way you could use the *pointer to `strcpy`* named `compare` to invoke `strcpy`, rather than `strcpy` directly: `cmp = compare(Name[j].nume, Name[j+1].nume);`

Comment: LOL.  Yes, you are most certainly right!  I'll fix that.

Comment: Now you've got my approval. No action necessary, but in the spirit of the section of code you've commented out, why not comment out the lot and write a `qsort` version? You've already got the `compareNames`, and that answer would be 1/ *so much shorter and more concise*, 2/ much more informative of the language and yet 3/ on topic as it answers the question about whether pointers can be used, by using *function pointers*! Eh, I often put too much work into my answers, but it seems it is incentive as you get more views after an edit (providing you don't edit too often)...

Comment: @Sebivor - Thank you for your thoughtful comment. The OP made a good effort on this.  I did not want to discount the work that was done, so answered the first part within the bounds of the original approach.  The second part was to illustrate that there is always more than one way to code something, and indeed to expose an alternative method that may not have otherwise been apparent to the asker.

Comment: I admire that level of respect. On the other hand, at the time of writing the comment yesterday, I thought there was only one block of code. The fact that you've included the `qsort` version is a huge step in the direction I thought you hadn't taken. If OP is reading this, not that my opinion should matter, but I think this answer is as "tick-worthy" as you'll get, *hintedy-hint*... It drags you in *the right way* to solve this problem, rather than *the pointer way* (which is technically an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: Longest known surname is less than 40 characters.